# Microinteraction and transition are same?

Tags: animation, microinteractions

During my last presentation on transition/animation, it was asked that "are microinteraction and transition same?"

I said no but could not back my answer.

Could someone please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Microinteractions**: Small "delightful" elements that are part of a whole experience.

Note: Microinteractions often use transitions to show the interaction between the user and the system.

Example: The "heart" feature on Twitter with its little animation

[image]

**Transitions:** A change in state that is done subtly in order to indicate change to the user whilst reducing cognitive load.

Example:

Going from one screen to the other, loading new content etc.

[image]

You can read more about microinteractions and transitions here:
https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/ux-design-best-practices-refined-microinteractions/

https://uxplanet.org/functional-animation-in-ux-design-what-makes-a-good-transition-d6e7b4344e5e

Comment: Great book on this: [Microinteractions](https://www.amazon.com/Microinteractions-Full-Color-Designing-Details/dp/1491945923/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1505830028&sr=1-1&keywords=microinteractions)